# Outlook receiving e-mail when synchronizing but not showing up in inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

The title says it all - when I synchronize, Outlook says its receiving x number of e-mails.

But they are not in the inbox.

Any possible causes?

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Mail Folders view so that you can see all your folders.  Open up the available branches and scroll down the list until you find a folder with a bold caption.  If other data (PST) files are shown, expand them as well.  Your email might be going to a junk folder, or it might be going to a different data file that you normally can't see.  The trick is to go to the folders view so that you can see everything.  Once you've found where the email is going you can make the required adjustments, like changing which folder is shown at Outlook startup.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the folder you are looking in is not the folder the messages are being sent to?